# Getting started with Open Liberty: 404

Tags: open-liberty

I'm trying to follow the guide here - https://openliberty.io/guides/getting-started.html.  I'm on the *Building and running the application* step.  I ran "mvn liberty:run" and Open Liberty started without any errors but when I go to http://localhost:9080/system/properties I get the error below.

> Error 404:
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No
> target servlet configured for uri: /system/properties

Any suggestions?

Comment: never mind.  rebooted & it worked

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each guide in the "Nice Work! Where to next?" section, each guide has link:

> Raise an issue to share feedback

which I would recommend for these kind of questions as you're likely going to get a quicker  response if you open an issue directly against the code you're using.